# TypeError: Image constructor: 'new' is required in ReactNative

Tags: javascript

The below code gives me the following error. What to do?

> TypeError: Image constructor: 'new' is required

```
<Image
  style={{}}
  source={{
      uri: 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png',
        }}
/>
```

Comment: Could you add some more of your code

Answer (score 8):

Make sure you import Image from 'react-native'

```
import { Image } from 'react-native';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting this error from a Next.js app then make sure to add the following import statement:

```
import Image from 'next/image';
```